# Should I combine the columns of a fact table to make it more narrow, or should I keep it more user friendly with a lot of columns?

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, fact

I have a Fact table that shows the results of KPIs. There are several KPIs, and some of these have a similar output.

My current columns are something like this:

```
KPI_ID, DOCUMENT_ID, TRUE_FALSE_FLAG1, TRUE_FALSE_FLAG2, DURATION_3, DURATION_4
```

So, for KPI number 1 (true false output), the last three columns will be NULL- values. Should I combine `TRUE_FALSE_FLAG1` and `TRUE_FALSE_FLAG2`? What is BEST PRACTICE?

In total, there are 18 columns, where 12 of them are either true/false- flags or durations in the shape of "number of days" (integer).

[picture of the two alternatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHK5C.png)

EDIT: 
KPI 3 could be "duration of problem", and you'd have a bunch of problems, each with a documentID, represented as a row. Dur_3 would be like 5 days, 3 days, 10 days, etc.  KPI 4 would be "Delay of fix after repair was ordered", and the answer would still be an integer in days. But completely non- related to KPI 3.

Reporting could be "average delay of fix". So roughly a select AVG() from table where KPI_ID = 3 group by KPI_ID.

Comment: With no domain knowledge about what the columns mean, the second alternative looks better to me.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: KPI 3 could be "duration of problem", and you'd have a bunch of problems, each with a documentID, represented as a row. Dur_3 would be like 5 days, 3 days, 10 days, etc.  KPI 4 would be "Delay of fix after repair was ordered", and the answer would still be an integer in days. But completely non- related to KPI 3. Reporting could be "average delay of fix". So roughly a select AVG() from table where KPI_ID = 3 group by KPI_ID.

Comment: As long as every KPI is only True/False, or has only one duration to report, you are better with Alternative 2. If there is a chance that any KPI would need to store multiple values, then you want to consider Alternative 1 or something between Alternative 1 and Alternative 2. 

You say "there are 18 columns, where 12 of them are either true/false- flags or durations in the shape of "number of days" (integer)." What are the other 6 columns. That seems that it would have a bearing on this.

Comment: @fredskogsBI . . . It sounds like the flags actually represent a different dimension, which is why I like the second solution.

Comment: Josh F: Thank you for your reply. The other six columns are just metadata, such as INSERT_DATE and UPDATE_DATE, and a few other non- relevant columns. I've made the ETL such that the KPI would not need to store values in multiple columns. That is; a KPI will not be needing to store both a T/F and a duration.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment, you are best with Alternative 2. Specifically, as long as every KPI is only True/False, and has only one duration to store, you are better with Alternative 2.

EDIT: with Alternative 2, each KPI can store one True/False value AND one duration value